# Global Styles do not override shadow dom style

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

According to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylefromoutside:

> Outside styles always win over styles defined in shadow DOM. For
>   example, if the user writes the selector fancy-tabs { width: 500px; },
>   it will trump the component's rule: :host { width: 650px;}.

This doesn't seem to work in my example. I have setup an app-overlay component. Inside I have a div with a .child class.  According to the above source, I'd expect the child to have the padding as set in the global scope:

```
app-overlay .child {
  padding: 0 25%;
}
```

See full example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQOmtxSA9AThCcNmrEJc?p=preview

Note that the padding that is set as global, is not applied to the app-overlay child (even though, it's supposed to *win over* the component's style).

Is there any step I'm missing?

Comment: In a native instance, you could use chrome developer tools to inspect and check the full css applied stack

Comment: Thanks @Attersson. I've checked it several times and it didn't work. Eventually I found the answer (see my answer below). Thanks again :)

Comment: Note that in the citation: "win over styles defined in shadow DOM" means "win over `:host` style", not over child elements styles.

Comment: I tried with `:host`. Still didn't work. It works only in case of inheritable properties. This phrase is also true if you style the custom element itself AFAIK.

Comment: Actually it works with :host

Comment: What works with :host? Could you please share an example (you can fork the plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/YQOmtxSA9AThCcNmrEJc?p=preview)?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ILTiLlyDtn7QtsRFPfUy?p=preview

Comment: That's not surprising - that's exactly what I did with my example. Color is inheritable. Try it with non-inheritable property and it doesn't work.

Comment: What non-inheritable property? http://plnkr.co/edit/XJOePRrmBM4RH91oYMkL?p=preview

Comment: Do you mean `what is non-inheritable property?`? If so, here's a link: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's just plain confusing so I put it here in case someone crashes into it.

Overriding via global scope styling works only for inheritable CSS properties.
If you want to set some non-inheritable property (like padding - see full list [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)).

So I guess the only way to do this for non-inheritable properties is by either injecting CSS via the template (e.g. calling a file) or by css variables.

Comment: Have you also tried `padding: inherit` and `!important` ?

Comment: About `!important` - that's one of the main things shadow DOM is here to protect our component from.
About inherit - you cannot inherit padding - it's non-inheritable :)
Just to make sure - I checked it in my code. You can try it in the plnkr in the question.